# xcode 4.5 launch image weird name concern (existing project)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

This is more of a concern rather than an issue. I tried to add all **launch images** to my existing project (iPhone, iPhone 3.5" retina & iPhone5 4") & the xcode keeps adding additional "@2x" at the end of the image file name. For example now all my new launch images are named like this

iPhone 320x480 = Default@2x.png

iPhone retina 640x960 = Default@2x@2x.png

iPhone retina 4" 640x1136 = Default@2x-568h@2x.png

Before adding i deleted all references & files from images folder & simply added new ones from project summary page. The app works fine I'm just concerned over the weird file name for the launch images. Has anyone encountered this ? This happens only with the existing project. How do I fix this for the existing project ?

**current images folder with weird names**

http://postimage.org/image/4kyy6pj6d/

**xcode warning when trying to add**

http://postimage.org/image/dhebodz6d/

Answer (score 0):

As of the newest Xcode, Any image named 'Default.png' or 'icon.png' with the dimensions of a Retina device's requirements will automatically add the "@2x" suffix to the end of the file name.

Therefore, you don't need to manually add the @2x suffix for essentially used images.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, 
Incase u've misunderstood i didnt manually name the files. At first i thought it could be of the original file names, so I just named the files 1,2,3 & dragged on to the summary page, but still the xcode puts additional @2x for each file. (even for the normal file for old iphone 320x480)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the property storing the launch image filename has been inappropriately modified. In Xcode, on the Info tab of your Target configuration, verify that the value for “Launch image (iPhone)” is `Default.png`, not (as it sounds like it might be right now) `Default@2x.png`. You can also verify this externally to Xcode; in `YourProject-Info.plist`, confirm that the string value for the `UILaunchImageFile~iphone` key is `Default.png`.

This value indicates the filename of the launch image for the bog-standard, pre-iPhone 5, non-retina-display iPhone, and is automatically modified by Xcode to obtain the names of variant files. If the value contains an extra `@2x`, then all derivative filenames will contain the extra `@2x`.